# What does \a mean in C?

Tags: c

I've just come across this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
printf(" \a ");
}
```

and the output isn't " \a " as expected. Does anybody know why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character . So, escape like `" \\a "`

Comment: `Does anybody know why?` Of course, the human race is smart.

Comment: Because `\n` also does not print `\n`, as you seem to be expecting. Why would you expect this to stop working?

Comment: @DeiDei Some would argue.....Trump..

Comment: @SombreroChicken Can't stump the Trump.

Comment: Search terms for Google, specifications, tutorials, books, etc: Programming language C; Syntactical element literal; Lexical element string. In short, [C string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `'\a'` in an escaped representation of the [`BEL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) charcater which has [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) code 7.

The `\` is used to "escape" a character that otherwise has no representation and cannot be written in a string by other means. Another examples are the newline `'\n'` and carriage return `'\r'`.

Answer (score 3):

Characters starting with a backslash `\` are called [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), these are special and aren't printed out. In this case, `\a` is the sequence for a bell ring.

Comment: "alert" or "audible", not "alarm".

Comment: @DyZ I'm just a simple chicken.

Comment: not a simple chicken, a chicken with a sombrero!